# How should I restore the default Windows 10 boot settings after removing dual boot?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot, desktop-computer

I have a computer that until recently ran both Manjaro and Windows. However, a couple of weeks ago, I removed Manjaro because I realized I didn't need it anymore.

The issue is, now I have an extra partition on my drive: [drive partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V8dn.png)

I have run out of space on my C Drive and would like to extend it to fill the unallocated space, but I need to change the boot settings to boot off of the first partition and not off of the E drive. I remember when I first created the Manjaro partition I had to change the boot settings TO boot off of E:\EFI to enable dual boot, but I forget exactly what I did and how to revert it.

If anybody knows how to fix my drive I would really appreciate it as I would not like to have to purchase another drive.

Comment: It seems you will need a software to assist you. Check the following links to see if they can help:  https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/changing-the-boot-partition/  or  https://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/clone-resource/move-windows-boot-partition-to-a-new-drive.html

Comment: I recommend AOMEI Partition Assistant. I've had pretty much the exact same problem as you before, and it really helped, and is pretty intuitive. https://www.diskpart.com/